# Remove add-in from excel that was added from a shared folder

Tags: office-js

This seems kind of silly but i have a simple add-in that i wrote for a single purpose.  That purpose is now done but i'm looking for the clean way to remove the add-in commands.  I can remove the group that the add-in commands are in from the Ribbon.  Is this the "Right Way" to uninstall a new style add-in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the shared folder from the Trusted Add-in catalogs, your add-in is removed as well